# Определение нового клиента

Tags: сессия, php

Здравствуйте

Стоит задача определения новых клиентов.
Есть интернет магазин, на котором будет небольшое функциональное обновление для A/B тестов. И новым пользователям будет отображатся одно, а старым другое.

Как можно определить какой клиент зашел, новый или старый ( если они оба еще не авторизированные ) ?

Спасибо.

Comment: IP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По кукам - самое простое.

Кому кука устанавливается и он ещё не авторизован - тому новое. Кому кука не устанавливается или пользователь авторизован - тому старое.

Если авторизовался, то обязательно установить спец значение куки "я старенький" на случай, если он выйдет из системы - ему всё равно должно показываться старое.